# Error en evaluar un HashMap dentro un ArrayList cuando genero un apk-release (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, hashmap

Muy buenas, tengo un problema al generar un apk-release para hacer pruebas.

Les comento, estoy trayendo de firestore un HashMap con urls de fotos, y esta lo estoy evaluando dentro de un ArrayList para obtener un valor y cargarlo en Glide.

Este es el código del que les hablo:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PictureViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    noticiaModel = noticias.get(position);

    holder.tituloNoticia.setText(noticiaModel.getTitulo());
    holder.userNoticia.setText(noticiaModel.getUser());
    holder.texto.setText(noticiaModel.getTexto());
    holder.telefono.setText(noticiaModel.getTelefono());
    holder.ubicacion.setText(noticiaModel.getUbicacion());
    holder.lat.setText(noticiaModel.getLatitud());
    holder.log.setText(noticiaModel.getLongitud());

    //transformando el HashMap a un arrayList para evaluar las posiciones del contenido
    indices = new ArrayList<>(noticiaModel.getFotos().values());
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>(noticiaModel.getFotos().values());

    Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(urls.get(0))
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imagenCard);

}
```

Este parte de código esta dentro de un AdapterReclyclerView que lo llamo y lo cargo en mi vista principal.

El problema va que cuando genero el apk-debug, da normal la aplicación, sin errores, les adjunto una imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, evalúa normalmente el HashMap para obtener un url y asi cargarlo en mi CardView.
Pero cuando genero un apk-release me sale error en la parte de evaluar el HashMap y hacer que se cierre mi app, les adjunto la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Collection java.util.HashMap.values()' on a null object reference
```

Espero me puedan ayudar o guiar en encontrar una solución, muchas gracias.

Comment: Como obtienea los datos del ArrayList, usas alguna API de Google?

Comment: Obtengo los datos de Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que `noticiaModel.getFotos()` retorna `null` es por eso que recibes un `NullPointerException`.

Lo que podrías hacer es:

```java
...
HashMap<String, String> fotos = noticiaModel.getFotos();
indices = fotos == null ? new ArrayList<String>() : new ArrayList<String>(fotos.values());
String url = indices.isEmpty() ? "" : indices.get(0);

Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(url)
     .centerCrop()
     .into(holder.imagenCard);
...
```

Como puedes ver, primero checo si el `HashMap` es `null`. También, modifiqué tu `.load(urls.get(0))` porque se puede dar el caso que `urls` sea `empty` y esto daría otro `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Pero por qué se obtiene null cuando genera un .apk release?, esa es la pregunta principal.

Comment: Por lo que compartiste, el código en sí se ve propenso a que recibas un `NullPointerException`, lo que compartí fué una pequeña solución. Respondiendo a la pregunta principal, estás usando `minifyEnabled true` para `release`? Parece que es un poco común: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666634/proguard-shrinking-causes-null-pointer-exception
Lo que también puedes hacer es añadir breakpoints en esa línea para ver los valores, añadir `debuggable true` en `buildTypes { release { ...` y correr la aplicación en debug mode usando `release` flavor. Espero y esto te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te comento, el problema era el minifyEnabled true, lo cambie a false y ya no obtengo un NullPointerException cuando realizo un apk-release. Aunque estuve leyendo un poco de cambiarlo a false, y no se si sea lo conveniente ya que uso API's de Google, pero bueno, gracias por tu ayuda, saludos!